# php response string in android

Tags: php, android, server

I am writing a simple app to send text files to server.  The code works fine, but the response from server is "OK".  In the php code (I found online), the return string should be "success".  Please suggest what I am doing wrong. The server response is:

> I/uploadFile(11338): HTTP Response is : OK: 200

but I want something like:

> I/uploadFile(11338): HTTP Response is : success: 200

in android for printing, I use:

```
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();  
               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
```

where as php looks like:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "/var/www/html/Extract/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: `responseMessage` is the text accompanying the result code. It is not what your server writes to you. That would be in the body.

Comment: you are doing it wrong because you are only getting response code not entire output

Comment: ah ok, thanks, can you pls guide then what should be in my android code.

Comment: use `HttpEntity entity = conn.getEntity()`  in java if i am not wrong

Comment: thanks for the pointer, thats not correct because conn is of HttpURLConnection type. I can google this.

Comment: The responseCode and responseMessage are provided by the webserver. Not by your php script. The output from php script you should read from the inputstream.

Comment: thanks for the comments, they did helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 success');
```